# Accessing multilayered structs results in error

Tags: c++

I'm working on a homework assignment that involves creating structures for vending machines around campus. I'm getting the error "'vendingMachines' was not declared in this scope" and I can't figure out the solution. Would I have to run a for loop in main to declare the vendingmachines struct?

```
struct Location
{
        std::string buildingName;
        int floorLevel;
};

struct Drink
{
        std::string drinkName;
        float drinkSize;
        float drinkPrice;
};

struct VendingMachine
{
        Location machineLocation;
        Drink drinkTypes[10];
};

struct AllVendingMachines
{
        VendingMachine vendingMachines[5];
};
int checkPurchase(std::string buildingName, int floorLevel, std::string drinkName, f$
{
        bool correct = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
                if (vendingMachines[i].machineLocation.buildingName != buildingName)
                {
                        correct = false;
                }
                if (vendingMachines[i].machineLocation.floorLevel != floorLevel)
               {
                        correct = false;
                }
                for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++)
                {
                        if (vendingMachines[i].drinkTypes[c].drinkName != drinkName)
                        {
                                correct = false;
                        }
                        if (vendingMachines[i].drinkTypes[c].drinkSize != drinkSize)
                        {
                                correct = false;
                        }
                }
        }
        if (correct == true)
        {
                return 1;
        }
        else
        {
                return 0;
        }
}
```

Comment: So where in your opinion is `vendingMachines` defined? It seems to be an array, but the only occurences of that identifier is as member inside the type AllVendingMachines. To answer, please make a [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to access `vendingMachines` in `checkPurchase()`.

However, that's a member of the struct `AllVendingMachines`. Which means *each* `AllVendingMachines` object will have a `vendingMachines` array. So *whose* `vendingMachines` are you trying to access?

The simplest solution I can see would be to take an `AllVendingMachines` object as a function argument:

```
int checkPurchase(std::string buildingName, int floorLevel, std::string drinkName, AllVendingMachines machines)
{
    bool correct = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (machines.vendingMachines[i].machineLocation.buildingName != buildingName)
        {
            correct = false;
        }
        // ...
```

Comment: Hmm, now i'm getting "undefined referce to 'checkPurchase(std::string...)'"

Comment: Did you make sure to pass `checkPurchase()` an `AllVendingMachines` object wherever you call it now that you've changed the signature? @Wes

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to do that! What would it be called? Would checkPurchase(std::string buildingName ... AllVendingMachines machines) work? I'd also have to reclare it at the top. What would it be call there. Would int checkPurchases(std::string ... object); work? Thanks! @scohe001

Comment: @Wes you should be creating some `AllVendingMachines` object somewhere and populating the array. That may look like `AllVendingMachines avm; avm.veindingMachines[0] = firstMachine; ...`. Then to call this function, you'll pass that object in: `checkPurchase("Tower", 5, "Soda", avm);`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Partially, mind taking a look at my code and letting me know if i'm on the right path? https://pastebin.com/zrmNhAdP @scohe001

Comment: @Wes kind of a long shot, but I'll be around for the next hour or so. If you want to [hop into chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203495/room-for-scohe-and-wes) and drop me a ping, I'd be happy to discuss your code with you.

Comment: Sounds great but I need 20 reputation to chat there haha @scohe001

Comment: @Wes looks like you're one approved edit or accepted answer away from that.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `vendingMachines` to be part of `struct AllVendingMachines`, but you have never created an instance of that struct. Therefore, not a single instance of the member array 'vendingMachines' exists.

You could simply make the array `vendingMachines` a global variable, i.e. move it out of `struct AllVendingMachines`, or you could create a global instance of `struct AllVendingMachines`, by changing the declaration to the following:

```
struct AllVendingMachines
{
        VendingMachine vendingMachines[5];
} all_vending_machines_global_instance;
```

In the latter case, you must change all references to `vendingMachines[i]` in the function `checkPurchase` to `all_vending_machines_global_instance.vendingMachines[i]`.

I don't want to encourage the use of long variable names, I just gave it this long name for clarity.

Alternatively, if you don't want to use global variables, you can make the function `checkPurchase` receive an additional paramater consisting of a pointer or reference to an instance of `struct AllVendingMachines` or directly to an instance of the `vendingMachines` member array.